# s-max blaupunkt travelpilot nx manual and repair manual

Tags: audio

I have been buying a sat/nav from 2012 and my car S-max 2,5 are from 2007, I can not get the climate control to function, any ideas ??

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your question isn't very clear, are you saying you have replaced your satnav and now your climate control doesn't work?

Comment: The satnav used to work? or never worked? when was it installed?

Comment: the radio and sat/nav works but not climate control.

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced the radio which where in the car to the sat/nav blaupunkt travelpilot nx.
My car are from 2007 and the sat/nav 2012 and now the climate control do not work.
All cables fits but the climate control wont work